# cycle FOR stops in the middle p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am doing this to clean the array theClouds = [];

```
function removeClouds(obj){
    var index = theClouds.indexOf(obj);
    if ( index > -1){
        theClouds.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(theClouds.length);
    }
}

function deleteClouds(){
    for (let u = 0; u < theClouds.length; u++){
        theCloud = theClouds[u];
        removeClouds(theCloud);
    }
}
```

But for some reason the loop stops in the middle, removes one or two and then ignore the rest, i have to click on the button that activates de function deleteClouds to force the loop and remove everything.

---

I forgot to mention, but theClouds[] is an array of arrays, I dont know if that concludes the same so theClouds = [ the.cloud = [x,y, image]]

```
Doing this will have the same point?
function deleteClouds(){
  theClouds = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: `splice` edits the array, so you won't be able to use indexes like that because the array indexes will be changed the first time `splice` is called. Why do you need to loop? Why can't you just do something like `theClouds = []` to remove them all?

Comment: In general removing items one by one in a loop should be done from the end to the beginning, because the length of the array changes, and your loop end condition with it. Having said that, this is very inefficient, as @Cjmarkham said simply setting the array to empty will do it.

Comment: If you're doing it this way because each cloud object needs logic applied (fade out or something) then do as @tromgy suggested and work backwards. 
`for (let u = theClouds.length; u > 0; u--){`

Comment: Done, how can i close or mark it as solved?

Comment: @FilipeCruz By posting the solution as an answer and accepting it